# Use php variable in SimpleXML

Tags: php, variables, simplexml

I want to return an array structure using simple XML. Everything fine, except when the XML has a tag with the same name as a PHP variable, like `return`.

Example:

```
$msg = simplexml_load_string($xml, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

Return

```
$msg->dynamics->details->flight->return-leg->airport;
```

How can I parse the return tag? I've tried something like `{return-leg}` but I get still error.

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried `$msg->dynamics->details->flight->{'return-leg'}->airport;`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
$msg->dynamics->details->flight->{'return-leg'}->airport
```

You can check examples here:

[PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php)

Comment: Oh I've missed that. OK , without error now, thanks a lot!